# Entity Framework eager load performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any change in performance between those two eager loading methods:

```
context.Set<Parent>()
       .Include(x => x.Childs) 
       .Where(x => x.SomeProp > 10)
       .ToList();

context.Set<Parent>()
       .Where(x => x.SomeProp > 10)
       .Include(x => x.Childs)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: The query is not evaluated until you do `.ToList()`, so those two lines of code are identical.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks for clarifying

Comment: I wonder if EF takes hints like these (Join before Selection) into account when computing the query and optimizing the query tree... however I highly doubt it.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, I highly doubt it too, but if I were that interested, I'd examine the generated SQL.